# How can I prevent the ActionBar from going out of the screen when scrolling a big EditText?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I've got this `EditText`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_editor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="textLongMessage|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:textAlignment="gravity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm using the support `ActionBarActivity`, and this is what I have on my Nexus 5:

[image: Half out of screen ActionBar]

As you can see the `ActionBar` is slightly scrolled off screen. I've made [a video](http://youtu.be/lINFD1qRcfY) that shows that.

I don't think this is the expected behavior, is it?
If it is, how can I prevent this? It seems very counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `EditText` in a `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_editor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="textLongMessage|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:textAlignment="gravity" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that a scrollable view plays well inside of a `ScrollView`, but I'll try this, thanks.

Comment: @BenoitDuffez Added a video.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this attribute in your actionbar's xml:

**app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"**